# Submit Button mousedown event

Tags: forms, mouseevent, onmousedown, mousedown

I had a question regarding a mousedown image swap with a submit button. here is the submit button code:

```
<input src="submit.png" type="image" class="submit" id="submit">
```

I tried to add an event using what I normally use for mousedown image swaps,

```
onmousedown="MM_swapImage('Image1','','submit_down.png',1)" onmouseup="MM_swapImgRestore()"/>
```

But I can't use the id of submit in the mousedown code, because I think it's associated with the button rather than an image.

Thanks,

Luke

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do here is change your submit button a bit. Usually you would have `name="submit"`, if you changed to that, you should be able to change the id to anything you want. The only reason this wouldn't work is if your using the id attribute in order to do something with some js onmousedown somewhere else?